# How to add new element below existing element using xml Document

Tags: xml, c#-4.0

I have an element Name "Dispute" and want to add new element name "Records" below the element.
Eg: The current XML is in this format

```
<NonFuel>
    <Desc>Non-Fuel</Desc>
    <Description>
    </Description>
    <Quantity/>
    <Amount/>
    <Additional/>
    <Dispute>0</Dispute>
</NonFuel>
```

Need to add new element under dispute.

```
<NonFuel>
    <Desc>Non-Fuel</Desc>
    <Description>
    </Description>
    <Quantity/>
    <Amount/>
    <Additional/>
    <Dispute>0</Dispute>
    <Records>01920</Records>
</NonFuel>
```

Updated Code:
Tried doing the following Code but getting error "The reference node is not child of this node":

```
XmlDocument xmlDoc=new XmlDocument()
xmlDoc.LoadXml(recordDetails);
XmlNodeList disputes = xmlDoc.GetElementsByTagName(disputeTagName);
XmlNode root = xmlDoc.DocumentElement;
foreach (XmlNode disputeTag in disputes)
{
    XmlElement xmlRecordNo = xmlDoc.CreateElement("RecordNo");
    xmlRecordNo.InnerText = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
    root.InsertAfter(xmlRecordNo, disputeTag);
}
```

Comment: Did you try anything? If yes, please show that code and tell us your problems with it. If not: why not?

Comment: Please show more code. It's unclear what `xmlDoc` and `disputeTag` are.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

InsertAfter must be called on the parent node (in your case "NonFuel").

```
nonFuel.InsertAfter(xmlRecordNo, dispute);
```

It may look a little confusing but it reads this way: you are asking the parent node (nonFuel) to add a new node (xmlRecordNo) after an existing one (dispute).

A complete example is here:

```
XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
xmlDoc.LoadXml(@"<NonFuel><Desc>Non-Fuel</Desc><Description></Description><Quantity/><Amount/><Additional/><Dispute>0</Dispute></NonFuel>");

XmlNode nonFuel = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("//NonFuel");
XmlNode dispute = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("//Dispute");


XmlNode xmlRecordNo=  xmlDoc.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element, "Records", null);
xmlRecordNo.InnerText = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
nonFuel.InsertAfter(xmlRecordNo, dispute);
```

Comment: Thanks, updated the code as follows-XmlNode root = disputeTag.ParentNode;

Comment: @Paolo How would this be done if the parent tag is presently empty? As in, he were trying to add the Records tag to inside NonFuel without any of the other values in it?

Comment: @Paolo what if I wanted to add attributes to the new node Records? Can I use your solution even when sibling nodes have the same name? i.e. I have a parent node <Books> with 6 child nodes named <book> and I want to add a new <book>. All the child nodes <book> have the same attributes, therefore I want a new node <book> with the same attributes

Answer (score 6):

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load("input.xml");

XmlElement records = doc.CreateElement("Records");
records.InnerText = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
doc.DocumentElement.AppendChild(records);

doc.Save("output.xml"); // if you want to overwrite the input use doc.Save("input.xml");
```

Answer (score 0):

Use 'AppendChild' method - to add as last element.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post;](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the OP](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead).