# Insert node in xml document using c#

Tags: c#, xml, hp-uft

I was trying to insert an XML node in XML document at a specific position.

This is my xml:

```
<Envelope xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <Body>
        <readContract xmlns="http://implementation.company.schema.reference">
            <ContactNumbers>10158</ContactNumbers>
            <productGroups>0085</productGroups>
            <indicationBalanceInfo>false</indicationBalanceInfo>
            <indicationBlocked>true</indicationBlocked>
        </readContract>
    </Body>
</Envelope>
```

And am trying to insert another tag `<productGroups>0093</productGroups>` below to the tag `<productGroups>0085</productGroups>`

Expecting like the below:

```
<Envelope xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <Body>
        <readContract xmlns="http://implementation.company.schema.reference">
            <ContactNumbers>10158</ContactNumbers>
            <productGroups>0085</productGroups>
            <productGroups>0093</productGroups>
            <indicationBalanceInfo>false</indicationBalanceInfo>
            <indicationBlocked>true</indicationBlocked>
        </readContract>
    </Body>
</Envelope>
```

Used the below C# code to achieve it.

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
string inputxml = this.StServiceCallActivity5.InputEnvelope.InnerXml.ToString();
//Here inputxml contains whole xml document.
string addxml = "<productGroups>0093</productGroups>";
doc.LoadXml(inputxml);
XmlDocumentFragment xmlDocFrag = doc.CreateDocumentFragment();
xmlDocFrag.InnerXml = addxml;
XmlElement parentEle = doc.DocumentElement;
parentEle.AppendChild(xmlDocFrag);
```

And it returns value like

```
<Envelope xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <Body>
        <readContract xmlns="http://implementation.company.schema.reference">
            <ContactNumbers>10158</ContactNumbers>
            <productGroups>0085</productGroups>
            <productGroups>0093</productGroups>
            <indicationBalanceInfo>false</indicationBalanceInfo>
            <indicationBlocked>true</indicationBlocked>
        </readContract>
    </Body>
    <productGroups xmlns="">0093</productGroups>
</Envelope>
```

Am a newbie to C# code, kindly help me to get the XML doc as expected.
your help is much appreciated.

Comment: Could you please point out specifically what is wrong with your output, i.e. how it doesn't match what you're looking for?  Please don't make us comb through your XML to try to figure out what's wrong with it.

Comment: It's just added the new element to the top node of the document. You need to navigate to the node that you want to add it to - in your case, the <readContract> node.

Comment: Use an XPath query like 
`XmlNode titleNode = doc.SelectSingleNode("//Envelope/Body/readContract");`

Answer (score 1):

When you do this:

```
XmlElement parentEle = doc.DocumentElement;
parentEle.AppendChild(xmlDocFrag);
```

You're appending the node to the root of the document. You probably wanted to select the actual `readContract` node that the item is supposed to be appended into. As an example:

```
XmlNode newNode = doc.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element, "productGroup", "");
newNode.InnerText = "something";

XmlNode readContractNode = doc["Envelope"]["Body"]["readContract"];
XmlElement groups = readContractNode["productGroups"];
readContractNode.InsertAfter(newNode, groups);
```

Of course you'd probably want to handle the case where there are already multiple child `productGroup` elements, but the idea is the same.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like namespaces are causing the problem. This worked for me:

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(File.ReadAllText("XMLFile1.xml"));
XmlNamespaceManager ns = new XmlNamespaceManager(doc.NameTable);
ns.AddNamespace("ns1", "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/");
ns.AddNamespace("ns2", "http://implementation.company.schema.reference");
var rootNode = doc.SelectSingleNode("//ns1:Envelope", ns);
var readContractNode = rootNode.FirstChild.FirstChild;
var newNode = doc.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element, "productGroups", "http://implementation.company.schema.reference");
newNode.InnerText = "0093";
readContractNode.InsertAfter(newNode, readContractNode.SelectSingleNode("//ns2:productGroups", ns));
```

Or if you don't fancy namespaces like I me, you can try a bit more "brute-forcy" approach:

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(File.ReadAllText("XMLFile1.xml"));
var newNode = doc.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element, "productGroups", "http://implementation.company.schema.reference");
newNode.InnerText = "0093";
doc.FirstChild.FirstChild.FirstChild.InsertAfter(newNode, doc.FirstChild.FirstChild.FirstChild.FirstChild.NextSibling);
```

It can be optimized but I think it helps to make the point that root cause is the different namespaces in the document.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use **XmlNode.InsertAfter Method**.

```
public virtual XmlNode InsertAfter(
    XmlNode newChild,
    XmlNode refChild
)
```

Where

`newChild = The XmlNode to insert`

and

`refChild = The XmlNode that is the reference node. The newNode is placed after the refNode`

Please check **[this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnode.insertafter(v=vs.110).aspx)** link for information.

And check **[this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16809421/1652222)** link with answer on **SO**.

**P.S.**
Always check other answers before posting new question.